# If I buy a gold edition of a game I already own on my PS4, will I have to redownload it?

Tags: ps4, just-cause-4

I have Just Cause 4 for free because of the PS plus free games, and there's currently a discount for the gold edition, if I buy it for the DLC, will I have to redownload the game?